# NullPointerException shown in Real-time crashes page of Google Play developer dashboard

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

Anyone can help on where the problem may be? at the moment I really have no idea where to look.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.im.zzc(im.java:0)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.im.zza(im.java:0)
  at <OR>.zza(im.java:0)
  at <OR>.zza(im.java:0)
  at <OR>.zza(im.java:0)
  at <OR>.zza(im.java:0)
  at <OR>.zza(im.java:0)
  at <OR>.zza(im.java:0)
  at <OR>.zza(im.java:0)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.aaw.run(aaw.java:0)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I think nobody can help you as you completely obfuscated your code.

Comment: I didn't obfuscate anything directly. So it should be some Library I used that is obfuscated already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was firebase remote config. I actually didn't create the remote_config in firebase dashboard yet and looks like in some limited cases the local default values xml file isn't working properly.
After adding the remote config variable in Firebase dashboard, the crash report stopped.